# JSONSchema local self-reference (recursion)

Tags: jsonschema

**How can I reference a schema (`B` in this case) from itself no matter where it is nested?**

I would like to be able to validate against schema `A` **and** against schema `B`. E.g.

```
from jsonschema import validate
validate(a, A)
validate(b, B)
```

Why? For unit tests and for speed improvements (if one of the `B`'s fails I don't need to validate `A`).

Schema `A` references schema `B` and `B` references itself (see examples below).

I have tried the following:

**a)** Using `definitions` in `A` works only if validating against `A`. Validating B fails with `jsonschema.exceptions.RefResolutionError: Unresolvable JSON pointer: 'definitions/b'`. Which makes sense because the definition only exists on `A`.

```
from jsonschema import validate

B = {
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "type": "object"
        },
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/b"}
        }
    ]
}

A = {
    "definitions": {
        "b": B
    },
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"$ref": "#/definitions/b"}
}

validate([], A)
validate([], B)  # RefResolutionError
```

**b)** Using `"$id": "http://example.org/B"` in `B` and reference itself with: `{"$ref": "http://example.org/B"}` makes an actual (unnecessary http request) to a URL that does not exist. There is no need to make that request as the information is present in the document. Attempts using a non-url such as just `#B` fails with `jsonschema.exceptions.RefResolutionError: unknown url type`.

```
from jsonschema import validate

B = {
    "$id": "http://example.org/schema/B",
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "type": "object"
        },
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {"$ref": "http://example.org/schema/B"}
        }
    ]
}

A = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"$ref": "http://example.org/schema/B"}
}

validate([{}], A)  # RefResolutionError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
validate([{}], B)  # RefResolutionError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Hey there! Looks like you're not sharing everything required for someone to give you an answer. Can you please provide your full JSON Schema? Can you please tell us the library you are using?

Comment: `from jsonschema import validate` is python code (but any other validator whould produce the same results I assume). I have added examples for what I have tried, you can copy and paste them to test.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem kinda like this. I found upgrading my jsonschema module from somewhere in version 3 to jsonschema >= 4.3.2 fixed it immediately so may simply be a bug.

```
pip install --upgrade jsonschema
```